# How to suspend watcher service so I can update file, then restart

Tags: java

I am using Watcher service to monitor a directory in Windows. If a change is done to a file, I'd like to write a timestamp to the same file. Of course, this is yet another modification to the directory and watcher then processes the event again. Is there a way to suspend watcher so I can update the file, then restart it so it can wait for the next event?

Perhaps there's a better suggestion???

```
 package net.codejava.io;

import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.FileLock;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;


public class DirectoryWatchDemo {

    static String logfile = "C:/Temp/log.txt";

    volatile static boolean suspended = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            Path dir = Paths.get("C:/Temp/");
            dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
            // System.out.println("Watch Service registered for dir: " +
            // dir.getFileName());

            while (true) {
                WatchKey key;
                try {
                    key = watcher.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!suspended) {
                    resume();

                } else {
                    updateFile();
                    suspend();

                }

                if (key.isValid())

                    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                        WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                        Path fileName = ev.context();
                        System.out.println(kind.name() + ": " + fileName);
                    }

                boolean valid = key.reset();
                if (!valid) {
                    System.out.println("Watch service invalid");
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

    private static void suspend() {
        suspended = false;

    }

    private static void resume() {
        suspended = true;

    }

    public static void updateFile() {

        try {
            File outfile = new File(logfile);
            if (!outfile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("No file exists...writing a new file");
                outfile.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outfile.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("TimeStamp: " + new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()).toString() + "\r\n");
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            System.out.println("done");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to interrupt the thread that is using the watch service, because that's the only way you get out of `watcher.take()`. Example with old-school threads:

```
public void start() {
    thread = new Thread(directoryWatchDemo::watch);
    thread.start();
}

public void pause() throws InterruptedException {
    if (thread.isAlive()) {
        thread.interrupt();
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

See [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) like [Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) and [Future.cancel()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-) for more flexibility.

Alternatively, you can `take()` all events and ignore them based on a `volatile boolean`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the volatile Boolean method? It would need to be ignored just before the file is updated from the timestamp, then re-enabled. Sorry I'm new at this...

Comment: @RLange Sure. You declare a `boolean volatile suspended = false`, and two methods `suspend()` and `resume()` which set the variable. Just after `watcher.take()` you check the value and, in case suspended is true, `continue` waiting for the next change. The other (non-watching) thread which would update the file and set timestamps can control which changes would be effectively processed by calling the two methods.

Comment: @RLange If you always have two changes in a pair, you could also count the changes and check whether the current change is odd or even; or use an Instant and then process changes only when there occurred another (recent) change.

Comment: Thanks steffen. Still working on the first suggestion. The problem is more than one timestamp is added at a change. I'm not quite sure what your saying in your second suggestion. "two changes in a pair"?

Comment: @RLange Well maybe I didn't understand your problem properly. I thought, you modify the file contents (which updates the timestamp), and then, after some time, you `touch` the file and update the mtime again. You only want to start processing after the second change after `touch`. If I'm wrong, please clearify your question.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. Actually, each time the file is touched, I want to add a timestamp. I've tried to add code here, but I'm not successful.

Comment: Alternatively, trying to start and stop the thread as another attempt, the thread terminates with InterruptedException and returns. Instead of creating separate methods, I've included the above suggestion code in main.

Comment: @RLange So when the file contents change, your watcher gets notified and makes another change to the file contents (adding a timestamp). I don't see that in your code (`updateFile()` is never called), but ok. In that case, I would do this: Declare a `Map<File, Instant>` where you collect times for files. You process only files that are either not in the map or the mapped instant is older than mtime. When you finished processing, you add the file to the map with `Instant.now()`. Remember to cleanup the map.

Comment: I just updated the original code block since I can't figure out how to add it here. It's only one file I'm trying to update.